# Windows: How to view a directory list in hex?

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10. I'm trying to figure out how I have two folders with the same name in the same location ("se 20210831" without the quotes). One was created by explorer, then the other by a photo program. No idea why that succeeded. The folder names look the same in explorer and in dir /a. No apparently abnormal characters, no trailing or leading characters, and no desktop.ini in the parent folder. The folders have different contents.

So I'm thinking maybe one of the characters is weird, like some alternative kind of space character. So I wanted to look at the hex of the directory listing for the folders. Is there any way to do that? TY.

Comment: Use the DIR tools to list folders and files to a text file and then open the text file with a HEX editor. (I use Ultra Edit).

Comment: If nothing else it would be good for you to to show us the copy-pasted output of your `dir /a` command. It is possible you have a unicode "non breaking space" or other odd character in the folder names. As suggested by John you can run `dir /a >dir.txt` to get a text file of the directory listing that you can then feed into a standard hex editor and which should show the differences.

Comment: Looking at the hex of a dir printout looks like a good idea. I'll call that the solution for this question.  But I'm still curious if there's a way to look at the actual directory hex; I suppose it would require something like a partition editor, but not sure if those can track out to subdirectories?

Comment: John, I'm a rookie at Super User. How do I accept your answer?  I don't see a checkmark next to your post, just up arrow and flag.